# Composer find 2 dependency with same name

Tags: php, logging, composer-php

Recently, I have updated my project denpendecies, and I get conflict. Two dependencies have files with same name "Logger.php"

Composer log:

> Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Logger" was found in both
>   "/project/vendor/whatsapp/chat-api/src/Logger.php" and 
>   "\project\vendor\apache\log4php\src\main\php\Logger.php", \the first will be used.

If I use one of them - my project doesn't work. I need to use both Loggers simultaneously, how to get this? May be put one of them into namespace?

My composer.json:

```
{
"require": {
    "php":">=5.3.0",
    "apache/log4php": "2.3.0",
     "whatsapp/chat-api": "dev-master"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please remove space before `"whatsapp/chat-api"` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes namespacing is the right way to go. It's always recommended and *good practice* to use namespaces for composer packages and projects to avoid any conflicts.

But unless you are the maintainer of one of these packages the only thing that you can do is:
Forking a package, adding namespaces and …

- … send a pull request to the maintainer.
- OR: … use your fork instead of the original package. (Note: You will have to maintain bug fixes and updates yourself after forking.)